# Can I upload with avrdude 2 hexes with 2 usbasp connected to computer, one hex with one usbasp ? If yes, how?

Tags: usb, isp, programmer, usbasp, upload

If I have connected 2 usbasps in the same time to ubuntu, can I upload 2 hexes one after the other(using avrdude) on each usbasp without disconnecting a usbasp ? If yes, how do I select each port for each hex ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add a little background on what you are trying to achieve. Also, how is this related to Arduino??

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130984/can-avrdude-address-individual-usbtiny-programmers